# How to "name" data in firebase from signup email

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

When storing users in firebase, How do you display the node as their email rather than the characters displayed in the image. I tried a bunch of different things and keep getting errors. Thank you for your help in advance. I appreciate it! :)

[FireBase Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3FiC.png)

```
$scope.signupEmail = function(){  

var ref = new Firebase("https://CoolApp.firebaseio.com");

ref.createUser({
  email    : $scope.data.email,
  password : $scope.data.password
}, function(error, userData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Error creating user:", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Successfully created user account with uid:", userData.uid);
    ref.child('users').push(userData); 
    $state.go('tab.home');
  }
});
```

};

Comment: Can you please post your firebase structure as text instead of a link. Also, in general, it's a bad idea to use node names that are actual data. You are much better off using push() to generate node names and then have children for changeable data such as an email address.

Comment: I disagree with that as a blanket statement @Jay. If items have a natural key (such as a uid for users), it is typically preferably to store them under that key and save yourself expensive querying later. I'm not saying using the email is the right approach here, but there are valid use-cases for having meaningful keys.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen You are very correct, sir. My apologies. I wasn't complete in my comment. A 'bad' idea to name parent nodes with names *that may be changing* (like an email address) as actual data - referring to the OP question about using an email address as a node name. Nodes can often refer to other nodes. So if the user changes their email address you can't just make one change. You have to 'change' that node name and then change the 200 other places that refer back to that node name. There are other issues regarding special characters in node names that also make it more work.

Comment: Yup, that's completely correct. You should type it in answer, so we can add some line breaks to it. :-)  In the case of encoding an email address, the approach I take below is non-lossy, so can be applied in both directions. But that isn't always the case.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Firebase documentation on storing user data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing):

```
ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).set({
  provider: authData.provider,
  name: getName(authData)
});
```

As you'll see, that stores each user under their `uid`, which is guaranteed to be unique across all providers.

If you instead want to store the users under their email address, you'll have to do some extra work. Firebase keys cannot contain certain characters (most notable dots: `.`) that are present in email addresses, so you'll have to encode the email address.

```
var encodedEmail = authData.password.email.replace('.',',')
ref.child("users").child(encodedEmail).set({
  provider: authData.provider,
  name: getName(authData)
});
```

It's most common in cases like this, to actually store the user under their `uid` (as in the first snippet) and to additionally store a mapping from the (encoded) email address to the uid. That way you can easily get the user both by their uid and by their email address:

```
ref.child("users").child(auth.uid).set({
  provider: authData.provider,
  name: getName(authData)
});
var encodedEmail = authData.password.email.replace('.',',')
ref.child("emailMappings").child(encodedEmail).set(auth.uid);
```